# ADB: How to install apk on multiples devices simultaneously using adb commands

Tags: android

How do I install apk on multiple devices simultaneously using adb command line instructions?
I want to install apk on two or more devices with single command, Is it possible?

I have tried using, below command.

"adb -s  install .apk path" --> this will install the apk on either one of the connected device but not on both the connected devices.

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

There is no "out of the box" solution. You have to put some time in there:

You can query all attached devices via 'adb devices' and have to process the output to install the apk on all attached devices ( do a 'adb install' for every connected device )

Maybe there is already a tool for this outside in the web, but i haven't found one.

See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#devicestatus for further information.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash (adb+)

```
adb devices | while read line
do
    if [ ! "$line" = "" ] && [ `echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` = "device" ]
    then
        device=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo "$device $@ ..."
        adb -s $device $@
    fi
done
```

use it with

```
adb+ //+ command
```